# Listing all the variables in a Python class

Tags: python

I've made a class, and after the program has finished running, I want to list all the variables I have kinda like so

```
var1: val
var2: val
etc
```

my class looks like this

```
class character:

   name = 'Player1'
   level = 1
   str = 100
   con = 80
   sta = 150
   critchance = 0.1
   critdmg = 0.5

   # for battle
   hp = con * con
   thoughness = math.sqrt(sta)
```

Comment: What do you mean "all the variables I have"? Do you mean all the current attributes of all the current instances of the class? Or actually all the variables currently defined?

Comment: I mean the variables i made for the class, like str and critchance

Comment: Take a look at the built-in `vars()` and `dir()` functions,

Comment: Are they class attributes or instance attributes? You apparently need to learn the differences in Python. You also should learn the proper terminology, such as "attribute" rather than "variable." And different instances can have different attributes (differing values and even which attributes exist): how should that be handled? There is no shame in needing to learn, since we all start that way, and I don't mean to belittle you. But you should learn some more about Python before you work on such things and ask such questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
for var in dir(character):
    if var[:2] != '__':
        print '%s:' % var, getattr(character, var)
```

Comment: Better use `getattr` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DeepSpace. I'm going to edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension (assuming Python 2.6+) to extract the variables from the class' `__dict__`:

```
print({k: v for k, v in character.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__')})
>> {'con': 80, 'level': 1, 'critchance': 0.1, 'sta': 150, 
    'str': 100, 'name': 'Player1', 'critdmg': 0.5}
```

Just keep in mind that in the example that you provided, these are class variables rather than instance variables.